# Creating multiple polyline features (trails) which have some common segments in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3

I have a trail system I'd like to represent in QGIS.  There are multiple trails which share some common segments.  I'd prefer to group the segments as trails to show distance and other statistics.

Can this be done without duplicating the common segments?

For simplified example:

Trail 1 is ABCDG.

Trail 2 is EBCF.

Trail 3 is HCF.

[image]